# Jupyter Notebook freezes at In [*]

Tags: jupyter-notebook

My entire .ipynb file has one cell, running only `print('hello world')`, and still no luck. I make sure no other processes are running but this.

I tried reinstalling Python and disabling antivirus. I don't have Anaconda.

It worked before, I don't see where this problem is coming from. My only guess is me changing some IPv4 properties has caused this, though I've changed it back to how it was. I've searched and tried many solutions but still no good.

I also notice that the circle next to "Python 3" in the navbar is now black instead of white as before, and now it cannot bind to localhost.

[image]
[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

Just changed the ip address in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` from

```
0.0.0.1 localhost
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

It's working normally now.